# Django: ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'

Tags: django, python-3.x, cors, pip

During my first Django project i encountered a strange problem: ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'.
I have installed django-cors-headers in my virtual enviroment using

```
    sudo pip3 install django-cors-headers
```

but with on success.

pip3 freeze shows package django-cors-headers as installed, but whenever i run uwsgi it shows exception traceback in log:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./login/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    File "/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/lib/python3.5/site-
    packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    File "/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/lib/python3.5/site-
    packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/lib/python3.5/site-
    packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
    File "/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/lib/python3.5/site-
    packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
    File 
 "/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", 
    line 126, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'
 unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import 
 error)
```

I tried installing different corsheaders versions, but with no success either. I am running Django 1.11.7 and Python 3.5.2. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT #1
I did follow offical install instructions from corsheader github repository. A have corsheaders in my installed apps in settings.py and coresheader middleware.

Comment: are you sure you are running the uwsgi using same the Python interpreter where you installed the package?

Comment: that was the case, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with the same problem - running pip3 directly from my virtual enviroment:

```
/home/pawel/pythonApp/myappenv/bin/python3.5 pip3 install django-cors-headers
```

solved the problem. The issue was that while running pip3 install, module was installed in general system-wide pip3 directory, not in my virtualenv directory. To start django i was using interpreter for virtualenv, not general interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach is to activate your virtual enviornment first and then install any package using pip.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you did not add 'corsheaders' to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. I have followed install instructions from gtihub repository.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the same problem by re install corsheaders by using this command:

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

NOT USE the bellow command(WILL GIVE YOU ERROR!!):

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```